# In angular ng-show without ng-click?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

So, I'd like to show a div when a flag is set to true. I've been able to achieve this with ng-show by toggling the value of the flag with a button click.

However, I'd like to use ng-show when that flag is changed by something other than a button click. There is a stream of events that I'm taking in from my backend service, and one of the events would flip this flag, but ng-show never seems to fire off unless I trigger it specifically with a button. Right now, the only way that I can get that effect that I want is just by directly calling `**document.getElementById().hidden = true/false.**`

Any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: Can you post some code? It sounds like you may have some sort of scoping issue, or the AngularJS digest cycle isn't running for some reason. In most cases, if you are truly flipping the ***same*** flag, then your ng-show should work just fine.

Comment: `<div ng-if="event" ng-show="something"></div>`

Comment: We need more than just that. Ideally the spots in your controller where the flag is set/changed, and more of the view. Also, using `ng-if` and `ng-show` in the same html tag isn't that common of a use case. What are you trying to achieve using both at the same time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe I'm misinterpreting your use case but it seems very simple: just use a variable in your controller / component and reference that variable in your ng-show.

```
// in your html
ng-show="myFlag"

// in your js
$scope.myFlag = true;
```

It may be a little more complicated depending on how you are using that backend service.